# Display error message when emails are sent to other domains using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am using c# .Net to send emails, My requirement is to send emails to a specific domain (Eg: @abc.com) and when emails are sent to any other email id other than @abc.com, users should see an error message that they cannot send emails outside @abc.com.

I know we can achieve it using javascript validation but is there any setting which we can set in config?

Thanks

Comment: Who knows. You haven't told us how you send emails or shown the code that does this. You using SMTP, MAPI, something else? Terrible question...

Comment: Are you sending an emails using javascript or by C#?

Comment: I am using SMTP using c#.

Comment: Its simple. Don't allow user to input domain. Just an email address without domain. Hard-code the domain in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this. Take a label and assign it `@abc.com`. You can also change the label text from config file.

[image]